# Deja Dup: Backup folder from the network

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, backup, remote-backup, duplicity

I know that it's possible to save backups on a remote location, but can I backup a remote location?
I have a server with data and a pc, that will keep the backups, on the same network. I can mount the data from the server on the pc, using sshfs and backup the mounted folder. I want to make backups daily and keep backups for at least a month. The question is, what will happen if the server stops or the connection is lost? Will Deja Dup make backup of an empty folder and on the next day, when all the files are reachable, make an incremental backup, which will do a backup of everything again? The server has about 300gb of data, that has to be backed up. On the first day, a 300gb backup will be made. Incremental backups will be small, about 50-80mb a day, but if the connection gets lost there will be an empty backup and on the next day a 300gb incremental backup. If the connection gets lost 5 times a month, that means that there will be 1.5TB of useless incremental backups.

Comment: If you are looking for a programming solution, you could test to see whether a certain file is reachable, or if the directory is empty/mounted before backing up.

Answer (score 0):

Deja-Dup is based on duplicity which in turn does encrypted backup of local files/folders to local or remote storages.

so, No, you cannot. however, it has been reported that duplicity worked flawlessly with fuse based or similar ways that mount remote file systems locally, so that local software can access it "as if" it were located on your harddrives.

..ede/duply.net

Comment: That's exactly what I was saying, but what if the connection gets lost? There will be an empty incremental backup on one day and on the next there will be an incremental backup that will backup everything again.